# Rails + Devise + Cancan select with dynamic, dependent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, html-select

I am new to ROR,
I'm using Rails + Devise + Cancan. I added more fields to the User (generated by Devise).
I need to do a select dynamic (state, city). Any tips or alternative without being Jquery

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking.  What do you mean a 'select dynamic' - if you either explain this, or provide an example from another product that achieves what you're after, we can probably help a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like [carmen-rails](https://github.com/jim/carmen-rails). Carmen rails provides a set of for helpers for providing country and state select menus. A nice [demo app](https://github.com/jim/carmen-demo-app#readme) has been provided with a detailed step-by-step guide on how to make the two dynamic. It does require a small amount of JQuery to filter the results, but you're going to have that with any dynamic select.

It looks as though the gem is still in beta, so be sure to explicitly set the version dependency in your Gemfile.

```
gem 'carmen-rails', '~> 1.0.0.beta3'
```

You should then be able to follow the rest of the example apps instructions.